# documentation (F1) broken in 11.3 with MacOS update (10.14.6)

Tags: documentation, mac-os-x, version-11.3

This summer [2019], after the MacOS Mojave updates (either to 10.14.5 or .6), my Mathematica 11.3 stopped being able to 'find' the documentation for anything that I click on, or even search for in the DocumentationCenter.  Doing either simply gives "*Your search - XXX - Documentation Center did not match any documents*".
So to look at any help, I must prepend '`ref/`' to whatever I'm searching for. 
I also notice that there are lots of error messages, most seeming to relate to JLink/Java...maybe related?

Comment: Does CMD+SHIFT+F work?

Comment: Can you add the error messages you're talking about to the question? That would help with tracking down the issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (11.3 on 10.14.5). But if the problem were affecting me, I would reach out to Wolfram Support.

Comment: Works with v11.3 on my Mac with macOS 10.14.6.  Your problem appears to be  local.

Comment: @Shadowray : CMD-Shift-f brings up the documentation window, but all searches there result in the same problem.

Comment: @LukasLang : the errors appear related to Java--
JLink`Java::argx: Method named searchTagged defined in class com.wolfram.textsearch.TextSearchIndex was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The arguments, shown here in a list, were {CreateUUID[],TextSearch`PackageScope`qUnion[TextSearch`PackageScope`qSearchBoost[TextSearch`PackageScope`qString[NormalizedTitle,table],1000],TextSearch`PackageScope`qString[All,Table]],{}}.

TextSearch::interr: An internal error occurred while performing the search. Please contact Technical Support.

Comment: I had the same problem.